# Apache URL based proxy redirection

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost, mod-proxy

I've recently installed PLEX Media Server on my server but i have some dificulties to hide it behind an Apache proxy...

I've found [this](https://gist.github.com/HazCod/3ef10a15f52c171a7839) vhost configuration to allow a subdomain based access to PLEX (eg: plex.example.com). My problem is that I don't want to create a specific subdomain, so I would prefer make a (transparent) URL based redirection like this :

My PLEX server URL : http://example.com:32400/web/index.html

What I want : https://example.com/plex/index.html

I tried the following vhost configuration :

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName example.com

ProxyRequests off
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPassMatch ^/plex/(.*)$ http://localhost:32400/web/$1
ProxyPassReverse /web http://localhost:32400/web

</VirtualHost>
```

But it doesn't work properly.

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, what is it doing?

Comment: When I have issues doing that, I've found that it's best to tail -f your error log and user the network monitor in a browser to see what gets are failing so you can rewrite your proxy

Comment: The output of the current conf is https://example.com/web/index.html. Moreover there's no error logs, just 404 error.

Comment: The logs are definitely your friend here. Turn up the LogLevel if needed, and check the access log too to be sure the queries are coming in as you expect.